# Saving Blog in Django with figure, Space, paragraph, link

Tags: html, django, postgresql, web-deployment-project

I am from embedded field but trying to learn web development and using `Django` for this purpose and using `Postgresql` as a back-end database. Questions can be silly but please understand that my level is beginner.

I am making one website in which user can write new blog entries. For this purpose, I am using `Textarea` to let user write the blog entry. My questions are

1) Is there any good text editor which i can embed in my website and let user write their entries. Right now, i can only write text but can't choose the font, upload pic, or format the text.

2) I am thinking to store the link to figure in the database and uploading the pic to the google drive or dropbox. is this good practice? can you recommend some other method?

3) How can i let the text saved in the database to know when to start a new paragraph? HTML tag will be enough, or do i need to use some other method?

Comment: Explore on this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-markdown